# How can a Java handler object catch all caught and uncaught exceptions?

Tags: java, android, exception

I want to make a central `Exception` handler, who will handle all exceptions thrown by our whole application. Uncaught Exceptions can be handled by:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

But if the condition comes like this, it will not be handled:

```
try
{    
    int i = 10/0 ;  
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // 
}
```

When any exception is raised in any of my classes, my central exception handler should get to know about it.

Comment: there is an open source project on github
https://github.com/tangrisheng/UncaughtExceptionHandler

May be you can try and see this

Comment: You could rethrow the Exception wrapped into a RuntimeException.

Comment: @Rene8888 will you plzz show me some code, whatever you are telling me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AtishAgrawal That sample project is for UncaughtExceptionHandling...
I want a handler for HandledException.
For example, if any exception will occure anywhere in my project,
even in try Catch block. My handler should get to know about that.


Try
{
   int i = 10/0 ;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 system.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
______________________________________________



Here in above code, exception will come and it will be handled by the catch block but i want here to handled it by Central Exception Handler/ Common Exception Handler.

Comment: In the catch clause just do a `throw new RuntimeException(e);` and a RuntimeException with your caugth exception as the cause will be thrown. Be aware, that the thread executing the RuntimeException if not caught, will terminate and the UncaughtExceptionHandler will be called -> Thats not good practice and normally not the way you want to handle your exceptions.

Comment: I have tried to make the question more clear by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your catch block:

```
try
{    
    int i = 10/0 ;  
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Edit:

You could add a class with static methods that you use to log exceptions if you don't want to crash your application.

```
public class Logger {
    public static void onException(Exception e) {
        //Do whatever logging you want to do here.
    }
}
```

Then just call the onException method in any catch block.

Comment: But if I'll throw exception there, It will crash my application.
I don't wanted to crash my app, I just wanted make a record of exceptions which is came during execution. Can you tell me, when try will throw any exception, By default which class is called and can we change system files.?